# React-Query setTimeout always runs and uncaught error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

In the following code I'm trying to throw an error if the request takes 5 seconds or more. This async function is used by the React-query hook. But that error always goes Uncaught, and triggers regardless of the request taking more or less than 5 seconds (this last one happens until I remove the `signal`). Why does this behaviour happen? Is there any solution?

```
 const test= async({signal})=>{
    const timer=setTimeout(()=>{throw new Error("Too slow")},5000);
    const response= await fetch("api/Categoria/ListarAcabados",{signal});
       clearTimeout(timer);
   
    return response.json();
    
  }
```

Comment: Do you call `abort` on the passed signal or does the `fetch` throw an exception?

Comment: Not calling abort. The error thrown is the one manually set, "Too slow"

Comment: With this exact code I only see three possiblities, that the "Too slow" error is thrown: (1) the `fetch` promise is taking longer than 5 seconds to resolve (2) `fetch` throws some sort of exception  (3) `signal.abort()` is called, which causes `fetch` to throw an `AbortError`. With (2) and (3) you won't reach the `clearTimeout` because this method doesn't have any exception handling

Comment: BTW the "Too slow" error will always be an uncaught exception, because you don't have the possibility to catch it anywhere. It certainly won't be caught by any exceptionhandling for your `test` like for instance `try { let json = await test( { signal})); } catch {}`  Not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you mate, now I understand better what's going on!. So, would wrapping the function in a promise and calling Promise.reject(new Error('Too slow')) inside a setTimeout make that error catchable?

Comment: No, because you are losing the context of that function. The only way to make this catchable is using something like [`Promise.race([timeoutPromise, fetchPromise])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) which will settle when the first of the promises settles